# Dynamic XML Template in TVML/TVJS

Tags: tvos, tvml

Does anyone know how to Dynamically generate a template in an apple tv app using TVJS/TVML?  Basically I want to hit my API, get back an array of objects and then insert that data into my XML template.

I've been searching for info on how to accomplish it but have come up short.  I've found many tutorials that use hard coded images, videos, etc but nothing dynamically generated.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I've figured this out. It wouldn't be difficult to generate a template on-the-fly, but instead I wanted to reuse the Presenter and the ResourceLoader, and to have the template as a *.xml.js file. Here is the solution I managed to arrive at.

For the initial view, I used a `catalogTemplate`, as demonstrated in [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/114886/beginning-tvos-development-with-tvml-tutorial). Instead of conference talks, however, I was displaying categories of men's and women's merchandise. Once a category was selected, I wanted to display a `stackTemplate` with a number of options for that category. The problem was how to pass any information, the title of the category in the simplest case, to the second template.

In the first template, I had the lockups configured like so:

```
<lockup categoryTitle="Women: Dresses" categoryDir="w-dresses">
  <img src="${this.BASEURL}images/dresses.jpg" width="230" height="288" />
  <title>Dresses</title>
</lockup>
```

In `application.js`, I had a listener attached, in the same way how tutorials show:

```
doc.addEventListener("select", Presenter.load.bind(Presenter));
```

Here is the second template (Category.xml.js):

```
var Template = function(categoryTitle) { 
    return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <document>
      <stackTemplate>
        <banner>
          <title>${categoryTitle}</title>
        </banner>
      </stackTemplate>
    </document>`
}
```

This is a JavaScript, so in your case you can pass into the function, say, an array of values and then construct the template accordingly. The tricky part was to pass a value.

First, I made a couple of changes to the ResourceLoader (this can be done better, of course, it's just a proof of concept). I simply added `categoryTitle` as an additional parameter to the top-level function and when calling the `Template`:

```
ResourceLoader.prototype.loadResource = function(resource, callback, categoryTitle) {
  var self = this;
  evaluateScripts([resource], function(success) {
    if(success) {
      var resource = Template.call(self, categoryTitle);
      callback.call(self, resource);
    } else {
      var title = "Resource Loader Error",
      description = `Error loading resource '${resource}'. \n\n Try again later.`,
      alert = createAlert(title, description);
      navigationDocument.presentModal(alert);
    }
  }); 
}
```

Finally, in the `Presenter`, in the `load`, I am passing `categoryTitle` to the `resourceLoader`:

```
load: function(event) {
  var self = this,
  ele = event.target,
  categoryTitle = ele.getAttribute("categoryTitle");
  if (categoryTitle) {
    resourceLoader.loadResource(`${baseURL}templates/Category.xml.js`, function(resource) {
        var doc = self.makeDocument(resource);
        self.pushDocument(doc);
    }, categoryTitle);
  }
},
```

This works for me.

One final note: for some categories, I had titles with an ampersand, like `'Tops & T-shirts'`. Naturally, I replaced the ampersand with an XML entity: `'Tops &amp; T-shirts'`. This, however, didn't work, probably because this string was decoded twice: the first time the entity was turned into an ampersand, and on the second pass the single ampersand was flagged as an error. What worked for me was this: `'Tops &amp;amp; T-shirts'`!

Comment: This works for simple string values, how do we pass complex JSON data ?

Comment: @VenkatapathiRajuM In the load function you would just create an object and pass that through instead. I'd also recommend reordering the arguments of loadResource so the callback is last.

Comment: What if I pass in an array of JSON data and need to, use AngularJS term, ng-repeat the template to generate array.length of <listItemLockup> and fill the variable with the JSON data? Like an Angular HTML template? The basic idea is to not hardcore the template but generate it based on the return JSON data. Thanks!

Comment: I am in a similar situation today because I dont know swift/objective c and i am just coming to the conclusion that I might actually be better off learning swift. All this tvml confusion is killing the whole point of using tvml.

Answer (score 4):

It is simple if you are using [atvjs](https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs).

```
// create your dynamic page
ATV.Page.create({
    name: 'homepage',
    url: 'path/to/your/json/data',
    template: function(data) {
        // your dynamic template
        return `<document>
                    <alertTemplate>
                        <title>${data.title}</title>
                        <description>${data.description}</description>
                    </alertTemplate>
                </document>`;
    }
});

// later in your app you can navigate to your page by calling
ATV.Navigation.navigate('homepage');
```

*Disclaimer: I am the creator and maintainer of [atvjs](https://github.com/emadalam/atvjs) and as of writing this answer, it is the **only** JavaScript framework available for Apple TV development using TVML and TVJS. Hence I could provide references only from this framework. The answer should not be mistaken as a biased opinion.*

Answer (score 3):

I'm using PHP to generate the TVML files dynamically, configuring the output as text/javascript format:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");

[run your PHP API calls here]

$template = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <document>
    ... [use PHP variables here] ...
    </document>';

echo "var Template = function() { return `". $template . "`}";
?>
```

Comment: Having some issues getting php to work for me. Im using php inside a product bundle template and my php looks like this:
`code

<?php
        header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");
        for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
          echo "<text>Hello World!</text>";
        }
        ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically generate a template by creating a dynamic string that represents the xml in a `TVML` template.

Review the code in here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/samplecode/TVMLCatalog/Listings/client_js_Presenter_js.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016505-client_js_Presenter_js-DontLinkElementID_6

This file has functions that can be used to create an `XML` document that can represent a view.

You can make an `XMLHttpRequest` (ex: [consuming API JSon calls through TVJS-tvOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553651/consuming-api-json-calls-through-tvjs-tvos/32578414#32578414)) bring back some JSON data and then dynamically generate an XML document that conforms to one of the TVML templates. Parse it into an XML document and then navigate to the document.

Comment: apple.com link is not valid anymore.